Android : Issue with pre-launch report : UPDATE - SOLVED
we can see error in pre-launch report. This seems to be specific for pixel 8 devices.
we are not using any payment setup wizard.
Does anybody faced similar issue? and how it got resolved ?
Surprisingly, our app is approved in BETA.
https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/issues/3436
as per this discussion , app is getting published to live with this error.
STACK TRACE :
Exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull (Parcel.java:3189) at android.os.Parcel.createException (Parcel.java:3167) at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:3150) at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel (DatabaseUtils.java:202) at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel (DatabaseUtils.java:154) at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.call (ContentProviderNative.java:764) at android.content.ContentResolver.call (ContentResolver.java:2466) at android.content.ContentResolver.call (ContentResolver.java:2446) at elwr.a (:com.google.android.gms@242335038@24.23.35 (190400-646585959):29) at com.google.android.gms.wallet.intentoperation.setupwizard.PaymentsSetupWizardAccountChangeIntentOperation.onHandleIntent (:com.google.android.gms@242335038@24.23.35 (190400-646585959):252) at com.google.android.chimera.IntentOperation.onHandleIntent (:com.google.android.gms@242335038@24.23.35 (190400-646585959):2) at ajom.onHandleIntent (:com.google.android.gms@242335038@24.23.35 (190400-646585959):8) at pkf.run (:com.google.android.gms@242335038@24.23.35 (190400-646585959):70) at pke.run (:com.google.android.gms@242335038@24.23.35 (190400-646585959):152) at emsz.run (:com.google.android.gms@242335038@24.23.35 (190400-646585959):21) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644) at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:1012)
Is this really an issue from app?
UPDATE : i pushed app with this error to production it went through. And when i uploaded new apk with new feature it didnt throw this issue

I have the exact same problem and have no idea where it is coming from. My app is built with Flutter. And the weird thing is that the app has no payment option and no ads. So I am wondering why "com.google.android.gms.wallet.intentoperation.setupwizard.PaymentsSetupWizardAccountChangeIntentOperation.onHandleIntent" is called at all.

i think they broke pre-launch tests

I have the same problem, but don't know what is causing this issue on beta launch

I'm using a payment system, but I watched the entire video and there is nothing related to the issue. Have you watched it? In my case, it never crashed or anything in the 5 min and something.

Unity dev here. Same issues, I tried uploading 5+ builds. Nothing worked.

I had the same problem. Updating "com.google.gms:google-services" from version 4.3.4 to 4.3.14 resolved it.

Many developers are experiencing the same issue and says that this problem happend in pixel 8. In test devices you can try to delete pixel 8 device and try again. I'm going to test it to bring the clues.

Was anyone able to reproduce this locally or is this only an issue with the pre-launch devices? I wasn't able to reproduce on a Pixel 8 Pro device locally.
